# SQL Query MyGuitarShop Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the question: 
6.  Write a SELECT statement that answers this question: What is the total amount ordered for each product? Return these columns:
The product name from the Products table
The `total amount` for each `product` in the `OrderItems` table

> (Hint: You can calculate the total amount by subtracting the discount
>   amount from the item price and then multiplying it by the quantity)

Use the `WITH ROLLUP` operator to include a row that gives the grand total.

This is what I have so far. I am not looking for a correct answer. i want advice on why it is not working and what i need to do. Thanks!

```
SELECT p1.ProductName,
       Sum(p1.ListPrice - ( p1.ListPrice * p1.DiscountPercent ) * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
FROM   Products AS p1
       JOIN OrderItems AS oi
         ON p1.ProductID = oi.ProductID
```

Error:

> Column 'Products.ProductName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: There is really no need to yell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add `group by` with `rollup`

```
SELECT isnull(p1.ProductName,'Total') As ProductName,
       Sum((p1.ListPrice -  p1.DiscountPercent ) * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
FROM   Products AS p1
       JOIN OrderItems AS oi
         ON p1.ProductID = oi.ProductID
GROUP  BY Rollup(ProductName)
```

**update :** I have changed the formula to find the `totalmount = ((p1.ListPrice -  p1.DiscountPercent ) * Quantity)` based on the explanation in question

Comment: all the total amounts are coming up as negative?

Comment: @ZackSpideyDavidson - looks like formula is wrong. Updated by answer check now

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
SELECT ifnull(p.product_name,'Total') As ProductName,
   Sum((p.list_price -  p.discount_percent ) * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
FROM   Products as  p, order_items as  oi
where p.product_id = oi.product_id
GROUP BY ProductName WITH ROLLUP
```